# two column primary key in mysql returning error and general funnyness

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a two column key in my mysql db (app_id, dated) and when i run the following query i get a problem

```
INSERT INTO `facebook_application_shares` (`user_id`, `app_id`, `dated`, `stats`) VALUES ('80', '269456199802533', '2012-04-24', '0')
```

I get the following error- even though the app_id is 269456199802533 and not 2147483647

```
Duplicate entry '2147483647-2012-04-24' for key 1
```

and then when i check the actual db table the value is actually "2147483647"

I am very much confused by this

[image]

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE facebook_application_shares` to your question?

Comment: Please ensure you include all unique indexes.

Comment: C'mon people, don't you recognize `2147483647` when you see it? It even has its own Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2147483647`, or `0x7FFFFFFF`, is the greatest number `MySQL` is able to store in an `INT SIGNED` column (which you `app_id` seems to be). Greater values just get truncated to it.

Make your `app_id` a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

Note that `INT(100)` is still a `4-bit` integer, with [**an optional hint to an application**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) not to show more than `100` digits from it:

> This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)

It's not that it is really able to store a `googol - 1`.